# SQL (HUE) : Is there any way to convert 24 hrs time into 12 hrs AM / PM format with hours buckets

Tags: sql, time, hiveql, cloudera, impala

I have table **A** which contains column **time** stored as timestamp datatype.

Table A: Contains time column in HH:MM:SS in 24 hrs format.

```
Sample data below:

time
12:32:45
16:09:04
09:02:16
18:34:33
08:59:30

Now I want to create a bucket based on hours and adding AM/PM.

eg: 
time between 00:00:00 - 00:59:00 = 12 AM,
01:00:00 - 01:59:00 = 01 AM,
14:00:00 - 14:59:00 = 02 PM and so on.

Desired Output :

time     new_time
12:32:45  12 PM
16:09:04  04 PM
09:02:16  09 AM
18:34:33  06 PM
08:59:30  08 AM
```

Comment: Tag your database, solutions will be likely RDBMS-dependent

Comment: @Stu It's Cloudera, Scripting is HUE- Impala. Similar to SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code. Replace `now()` with `time` for your query.

```
SELECT now(), lpad(CONCAT ( 
CAST (extract(hour from now()) + CASE WHEN extract(hour from now()) >12 THEN -12 
WHEN extract(hour from now())=0 THEN 12 
ELSE 0  END AS string) , 
CASE WHEN extract(hour from now())  >=12 THEN ' PM' ELSE ' AM' END),5,'0') as new_time
```

Explanation -
firstly i am checking if hour is >12. If yes, deducting 12 to get the hour.
Then setting up AM/PM based on hour.
lpad is used to make sure you get data in 01 AM format.
[image]

Comment: Thank you @KoushikRoy I wanted to have a solution that applies to the entire column level and not on individual values as the column has millions of records.

Comment: I used your `time` column and modified the SQL. i was trying to show you how it works with an example.

Comment: When I take ```time``` as a column it throws AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: left(TIMESTAMP, TINYINT). I am using Cloudera CDH6.3

Comment: sorry i dint notice the time is timestamp, i corrected the query. Could  you pls try it?

Comment: @kaushikRoy This is working except for two things 1: When the time has values in the range of 12 like if time is between 12:00:00 to 12:59:00 it shows 0 PM and 2: Can we also add 0 (zero) before single-digit time like currently for b/w 15:00:00 - 15:59:00 its showing as 3 PM and I need to have 03 PM. Thank you again.

Comment: 1 - i thought about it. in case of time between 12:00 to 12:30, what you want to see 12 PM ? 2. yep, i can fix it.

Comment: 1. Yes, if b/w 12:00 to 12:59:00 I want to see 12 PM. It's a 1-hour bucket and not 30 min. and if its b/w 00:00:00 to 00:59:00 desired output should be 12 AM

Comment: Could you please check new sql?

Comment: It is properly working however only one point left is when the time column has values between 00:00:00 - 00:59:59 i.e. (12 AM - 12:59 AM) it is displaying output as ```00 AM``` Ideally, it should be ```12 AM```

Comment: Could you please check new sql?